# Elasticserach with python: how to search for documents that do not equal

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to get all the those documents where session is not "None". No matter which way  try it, I get a error:

```
query = {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not" : {
        "term" : {
          "session" : "None"
         }
       }
      }
    }


    #resp = es.search(index="test-sql-index", query={"must_not": {"session" : session_ID}}, size=1000)
   
    resp = es.search(index="test-sql-index", body=query)
```

I always get the following error:

> RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [bool].')
> File "C:\Users\Mahir\Neuer Ordner\ElasticPython.py", line 122, in searchReturncode
> resp = es.search(index="test-sql-index", body=query)

I am trying to get all the those documents where session is not "None"

I also tried it this way:

```
resp = es.search(index="test-sql-index", query={"bool":{"must_not": {"returncode" : "None"}}}, size=1000)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to start your query by the term `query`

```
query = {
"query":{
    "bool" : {
      "must_not" : [{
        "term" : {
          "session.keyword" : "None"
         }
       }]
      }
    }}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! That worked. Do you have any idea why it still shows me results where session is set to "None"? Documents that include this "'session': 'None'," still appear

Comment: Is your field `Session` type Keywords?

Comment: I dont really know how to check for that, the Index was already existing

Comment: `Get index_name/_mapping` on kibana

Comment: I got it now, its type Keyword: "session": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
            "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
            }

Comment: i edited my answer check again